# Extract text in two columns from a string

Tags: r, regex, pattern-matching, stringr

I have a table where one column has data like this:

```
table$test_string<- "[projectname](https://somewebsite.com/projectname/Abc/xyz-09)"
```

1.) I am trying to extract the first part of this string within the square brackets in one column, i.e.

`table$project_name <- "projectname"`

using the regex:

```
project_name <- "^\\[|(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9])+|\\]$"
table$project_name <- str_extract(table$test_string, project_name)
```

If I test the regex on 1 value (1 row individually) of the table, the above regex works with using
`str_extract_all(table$test_string, project_name[[1]][2])`.

However, I get NA when I apply the regex pattern to the whole table and an error if I use str_extract_all.

2.) Second part of the string, which is a URL in another column,

`table$url_link <- "https://somewebsite.com/projectname/Abc/xyz-09"`

I am using the following regex expression for URL:

`url_pattern <- "http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\\(\\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+"`

`table$url_link <- str_extract(table$test_string, url_pattern)`

and this works on the whole table, however, I still get the ')' last paranthesis in the url link.

What am I missing here? and why does the first regex work individually and not on the whole table?
and for the url, how do I not get the last paranthesis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It feels like you could simplify things considerably by using parentheses to group capture. For example:

```
test_string<- "[projectname](https://somewebsite.com/projectname/Abc/xyz-09)"

regex <- "\\[(.*)\\]\\((.*)\\)"

gsub(regex, "\\1", test_string)
#> [1] "projectname"

gsub(regex, "\\2", test_string)
#> [1] "https://somewebsite.com/projectname/Abc/xyz-09"
```

Comment: Wow, this was a lot easier than my way! Worked like a charm!! Thanks a ton!!

Comment: Glad to help! Feel free to accept the answer you end up using (there is at least another good one available, which you may want to try).

Answer (score 0):

We can make use of convenient functions from `qdapRegex`

```
library(qdapRegex)
rm_round(test_string, extract = TRUE)[[1]]
#[1] "https://somewebsite.com/projectname/Abc/xyz-09"

rm_square(test_string, extract = TRUE)[[1]]
#[1] "projectname"
```

#### data

```
test_string<- "[projectname](https://somewebsite.com/projectname/Abc/xyz-09)"
```